# Oracle SQL - where clause using datetime value from another table

Tags: oracle, datetime-format, toad

I have a datetime value from another table which I want to copy and paste into another script but getting error messages: not a valid month.

The date value from table1 is also in the format 17/06/2019 2:25:49 PM

```
select *
from table1
where date >= '28/02/2019 3:15:04 PM'
```

have also tried changing to dd mmm yyyy, , error msg: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

```
select *
from table1
where date >= '28 Feb 2020 3:15:04 PM'
```

and have tried To_Date('28/02/2020 3:15:04 PM','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), error msg: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

```
select *
from table1
where date >= To_Date('28/02/2020 3:15:04 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: are the column data type from where you want to copy and to where you want to paste a `date` data type?

Comment: In Oracle, dates do not have a format. they are stored in an internal binary format.

Comment: 28/02 is dd/mm but you wrote mm/dd. Obviously there is no month 28, that's why you get that error. Then: 3:15:04 PM is in the format 'hh:mi:ss PM'  not 'hh24:mi:ss'.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy, I've update to >= To_Date('28/02/2020 3:15:04 PM','dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss PM') and seem to work now, is there any way to not have to add PM or would automatically recognise the PM or AM? eg. and date between  To_Date('28/02/2020 3:15:04 PM','dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss PM')
and To_Date('31/03/2020 11:58:47 AM','dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')

Comment: @user15676 - You may use 'AM' or 'PM' or even 'am' or 'pm' - any one of these format components will recognize all the others. I believe 'AM' is most commonly used.